# Is the singleton subset of a topological group closed?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Is it true that a point in any topological group is a closed set?

I am not sure how to show this using only the definition of a topological group although it should be easy.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: One-point sets are closed if and only if the group is Hausdorff. (To wit: it's not always the case.)

Comment: Note that it suffices to prove that $\{1_G\}$ is closed.

Comment: Note also, following from the comment of @DanielFischer , that a topological group is Hausdorff if and only if it is a $T_0$ space (AKA a Kolmogorov space). For this, it is enough to show that for all $g\in G$, there exists a neighbourhood of the identity which does not contain $g$.

Comment: Note also that you can factor out the closure of the identity element $e_G$ ( $\{e_G\}$ is a normal subgroup and the closure of a normal subgroup it always normal). Then you get a group which equipped with the quotient topology is homeomorphic to the Kolmogoroff quotient.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Thanks- that definitely answers my query.

Answer (score 3):

You can take any group $G$ and have the indiscrete topology on it, where only $\emptyset$ and $G$ are open. For all groups except the trivial, there are no closed singletons in it.